# How to pass an array of data to one component to another component using history.push in ReactJs when fetched using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to pass some fetched data to another component when routing the page using history.push() but it's not passing due to some async/sync issue according to my knowledge. How to solve this

this is the data fetching(using Axios) and data passing component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {analyse} from '../../services/dataFetching';

function testFunction() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetch = () =>{
       
        analyse() // this the axios based function which is defined in the service class
        .then(response => {
            setData(response)})

        .then(
                history.push({ 
                pathname: '/somepage',
                state:data}))

        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error) })};

    return (
        <div> <button onClick={fetch}>FETCH DATA</button> </div>
    )
}

export default testFunction
```

in the above class, it is fetching data and it can be logged in the console.

here the data receiving child component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function testFunction2() {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    console.log("state: ", state) 

    return (
        <div>
            {state}
        </div>
    )
}

export default testFunction2
```

to here it is always receiving an empty array

Comment: What about just passing the data needed for the request and make the request in the second component?

Comment: Here a simple code : https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-routing-u7foz?from-embed=&file=/src/components/UserForm.js

Comment: @charlietfl actually in here doing getting some input from the user and need to show some result then passing to next component from more results like that. I can't call the same request in both components because it takes like 5-6 minutes(fetching from the data science component).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the function returned by the useState call doesn't return a promise, i.e) setData isn't a promise, so it is resolved instantly, causing the next step in the chain, which is history.push(), to be called immediately without waiting for setData() to finish execution. What you want to do here is have history.push() execute after your state is set, which can be done using the useEffect() hook.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {analyse} from '../../services/dataFetching';

function testFunction() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
    history.push({ 
                pathname: '/somepage',
                state:data})
    },[data])

    const fetch = () =>{
       
        analyse() // this the axios based function which is defined in the service class
        .then(response => {
            setData(response)})

        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error) })};

    return (
        <div> <button onClick={fetch}>FETCH DATA</button> </div>
    )
}

export default testFunction
```

Now, the function specified in the useEffect hook will be called whenever the data variable is modified, which happens when the state is successfully set.